# Spring boot | JPA - What is a good structure for Ordering, Inventory, and Billing Entities

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa

I am working on a veterinary clinic system. I have an inventory page where I have details about the products, price, stock, etc. And I also have a menu page where I display those products and this is where the user will add to cart the products which will then be displayed at the Billing page which is basically the invoice showing the total amount, quantity of each product, etc.

```
public class Order {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Quantity should have a minimum value of 1")
private Integer quantity;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Sub Total should have a minimum value of 1")
private Float subTotal;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Total should have a minimum value of 1")
private Float total;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("order")
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "order")
private List<Inventory> inventory;

public class Inventory {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Integer id;
@Size(min=2, message = "Product Name should have atleast 2 characters")
private String name;
@Size(min=2, message = "Category should have atleast 2 characters")
private String category;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Stock should have a minimum of 1 value")
private Integer stock;
@Min(value = 1, message = "Price should have a minimum of 1 value")
private Float price;
@Column(columnDefinition = "TEXT")
private String base64Data;

@JsonIgnoreProperties("inventory")
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = true)
private Order order;
```

I haven't gotten to the Billing entity yet. I am a bit lost at how to relate each entities with each other. i.e what type of relationship should I use, what fields should I include in each entity that would make it plausible at the end. I am still very new to all of this so it would be much appreciated if someone could help me out.

Comment: In general your question is not suitable for StackOverflow in this form. Please describe your entities and their fields as textual description, and what you tried to make code for them. Then we can help you to verify if the written code suites the model you described. We don't know your "real world" so we cannot perform the business analysis part for you.